# Batch script capture output from cmd

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I'm trying to capture the stoutput from "call ppm query assert" and if it equals "*** no packages installed matching 'assert' ****" or better yet contains the string "no packages" do "something" .. being install the package. Any suggestions would be great.. I been scratching my head to long with this. thanks in advance.

```
:datetime
echo Installing datetime package
call ppm query assert
IF "%OUT%" == "*** no packages installed matching 'assert' ***" (
    echo testtest
::ppm install datetime
pause
) ELSE (
GOTO :win32::api
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
call ppm query assert | findstr /c:"no packages" >nul && (
  echo package not found
) || (
  echo package found
)
```